# Proccess info gives an error but a bat file does not

Tags: c#

I try to start ilasm from C# using class ProcessInfo

```
 string arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" /exe /output:\"{1}\"  /debug=IMPL", ilFullFileName, exeFileFullName);
 ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(CILCompiler, arguments);
 processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
 processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\";
 using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
 {
    process.WaitForExit();
 }
```

the arguments are:

```
"path_to_il.il" /exe /output:"path_to_exe.exe"  /debug=IMPL
```

and then it gives me the error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000007b). Click Ok to close the application.
```

The odd part of that is, when I do exactly the same actions manually using bat file

```
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe"  "path_to_il.il" /exe /output:"path_to_exe.exe"  /debug=IMPL
pause
```

it does work.

What did I miss?

Comment: Why did you give CILCompiler as the first input to ProcesStartInfo? Arent you specifying ilasm.exe  in arguments? Can you try setting ProcessStartInof.FileName to ilasm.exe and remove ilasm.exe from arguments?

Comment: It doesn't exist in arguments.

Comment: Sorry, Can you try setting ProcessStartInof.FileName to ilasm.exe

Comment: It's already set by constructor new ProcessStartInfo(CILCompiler, arguments);

Comment: try removing the trailing backslash from WorkingDirectory parameter. Also can you verify that the input to processStartInfo is indeed ilasm.exe?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19434/discussion-between-ganesh-r-and-alan-dert)

Comment: basically set the filename such that you give the full path to ilasm.exe

Comment: thanks, but I already solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the file name as well:

```
        processStartInfo.FileName = "ilasm.exe";
```